# Access other fragment data

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm having some trouble, and I have done research on the problem but it did not help me.

I have a Main.java class, which is template made pager view of fragments.

I did not modify it in any way, except for getItem() method which now returns my own fragments.

My fragment A is collecting accelerometer data, saving last 120 records in an ArrayList.
It also has graph plots, with Series objects, which I would like to access from fragment B.

This is what I want to do:

In fragment B user presses a button "record data"

This results in fragment A boolean field "recordingOn" changing to true

Now in fragmentA onSensorChange method, after checking for "recordingOn", if it's true it will pass data to an ArrayList that is a field in fragment B

How do I access these fields?

Answer (score 1):

from fragment call

Fragment frag = getActivity().getFragmentManager()..findFragmentByTag("fragment to find tag");

Answer (score 1):

Greensy answer is a valid option (I upvoted him) but you can also refrain from doing so much DataPassing between fragments and let the Activity be a manager for all that.

For that you can create public methods and interfaces in the fragments and let/force the activity implement the interfaces.

Simple example:

```
public class Act extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
     @Override
     OnClick(View v){
        if(v.getId()==R.id.btn_recordData){
           fragA.startRecording();
        }
     }
}
```

then FragA you must create that method:

```
 public class FragA extends Fragment{
    private boolean isRecording
    public void startRecording(){ isRecording = true; // also init the sensor stuff }
    public void stopRecording() { isRecording = false; // also stop the sensor stuff }
 }
```

then on FragB you can:

```
 public class FragB extends Fragment{
      onCreateView(...){
          // initialise all the views and find the button, let's call it Button btn;
          btn.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener)getActivity());
      }
 }
```

does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

A way to do that is to use your own [Application class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) and store your `ArrayList` in there

You can then access it in any point of your application, if you got a `Context` :

```
ArrayList<AccelerometerData> myAccelerometerData = ((MyApplication) mContext.getApplicationContext()).getAccelerometerData();
```

Be carefull about this solution since your `ArrayList` will be alive during all the application run